# Posting a js array to PHP and using it in a database query

Tags: javascript, php, sql, arrays, where-clause

I want my javascript function to pass multiple variables down to PHP and then have PHP use those variables in a select statement. Currently my code works when I just pass the variables that are strings but as soon as I added this line: `AND newVar IN ('+$myVarArrayPHP+')` into the query, the query doesn't pull anything from the database(There definitely is a row of data that matches the query). Thanks so much!!

JS:

```
var varSring1= "test";
var varString2= "testing";
var varArray= [""] // the number of elements in the array is determined dynamically and are all strings for example: ["grape","mango","apple"]
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "myPHPFile.php",
   data: {
       myVar1: varSring1,
       myVar2: varString2,
       myVarArray: varArray
     },
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (response)
       if ((response[0]['var1']) != null) {
       document.getElementById("tc-unique-ID-1").value = (response[0]['var1']);}

      if ((response[0]['var2']) != null) {
      document.getElementById("tc-unique-ID-2").value = (response[0]['var2']);}
   error: function (err) {
            console.error(err.responseText);
        }
    });


}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST[myVar1]) && ($_POST[myVar2]) && ($_POST[myVarArray])){  //check if $_POST[''] exists
  $myVar1PHP= $_POST[myVar1];
  $myVar2PHP= $_POST[myVar2]; 
  $myVarArrayPHP= $_POST[myVarArray]; 

  $ret = pg_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE  var1= '$myVar1PHP' AND var2= '$myVar2PHP' AND newVar IN ('+$myVarArrayPHP+');")

  $results=array();
  while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($ret) ){
    array_push( $results,$row);
  }  


}
```

Comment: Have a look into https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php because your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: You need to convert the `$myVarArrayPHP` to something SQL can deal with. Normally, your code should throw an exception like `Array to String conversion` because you are using your array like a string: `newVar IN ('+$myVarArrayPHP+');`. You can see this behavior if you move your SQL statement to a new variable and add `echo $sql_statement;` after it. How should your array be converted to a string? Can you please provide an example value for this array?

Comment: @johannes ["grape","mango","apple"] is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell PHP how to deal with the array, e.g. by using `implode` ([PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)):

```php
//check if $_POST['...'] exists
if(isset($_POST["myVar1"]) && isset($_POST["myVar2"]) && isset($_POST["myVarArray"]) && isset($_POST["differentPostedVar"]) && isset($_POST["lastPostedVar"])){
    $myVar1PHP= $_POST["myVar1"];
    $myVar2PHP= $_POST["myVar2"]; 
    $myVarArrayPHP= $_POST["myVarArray"];
    $differentPostedVar = $_POST["differentPostedVar"]; // assumption
    $lastPostedVar = $_POST["lastPostedVar"];

    // newVar IN ($3, $4, $5); and so on
    $first_sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE  var1= $1 AND var2= $2 AND newVar IN (put_placeholders_here);";
    $results = execute_prepared_statement($connection, $first_sql, "first_sql", array($myVar1PHP, $myVar2PHP), $myVarArrayPHP);

    if(0 == count($results)) {
        $second_sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE differentVar= $1 AND var2= $2 AND newVar IN (put_placeholders_here);";
        $results = execute_prepared_statement($connection, $second_sql, "second_sql", array($differentPostedVar, $myVar2PHP), $myVarArrayPHP);

        if(0 == count($results)) {
            $third_sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 3rdQ= $lastPostedVar;";
            $results = execute_prepared_statement($connection, $third_sql, "third_sql", array($differentPostedVar, $myVar2PHP), $myVarArrayPHP);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($results);
}

function execute_prepared_statement($connection, $sql, $query_name, $normal_params, $in_array = null) {
    $elementsCount = count($in_array);
    $no_of_other_params = count($normal_params); // you need to start with $3 because of $myVar1PHP and $myVar2PHP

    // generate an array that holds a placeholder ($3, $4 etc.) for every value in $myVarArrayPHP
    $binding_placeholders = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $elementsCount; $i++) {
        $binding_placeholders[] = "$" . ($i + $no_of_other_params + 1);
    }

    // array to string conversion (will produce "$3,$4,$5" etc.)
    $placeholders = implode(",", $binding_placeholders);
    // replace placeholder string with actual placeholder string 
    $sql = str_replace('put_placeholders_here', $placeholders, $sql);

    $ret = pg_prepare($connection, $query_name, $sql);

    // using array_merge to create one array having all parameters
    $parameters = array_merge($normal_params, $in_array); 

    $result = pg_execute($connection, $query_name, $parameters);

    $results=array();

    while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($ret) ){
        array_push( $results, $row );
    }

    return $results;
}
```

`implode(',', $array);` converts `["grape", "mango", "apple"]` to a string: `grape,mango,apple`. Now SQL is able to deal with it.

Documentation for the `pg_prepare()` prepared statement: [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php)

**EDIT**

1. I was missing the `"` around the indices of the arrays
2. `implode()` was the right idea but I used it for the wrong thing because it will generate `"grape, mango, apple"` so your database will look exactly for this string. Instead, we need to look for `"grape", "mango", "apple"`.
3. Using the [`splat`](https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator) operator of PHP to disassemble `$myVarArrayPHP` dynamically.

Inspiration from https://supunkavinda.blog/php-mysqli-prepared-where-in.

**2ND EDIT**
Answer to another question by thread opener to execute several queries based on `count($results)` of previous statements.

Comment: What has changed? Have you added the `echo $sql;` after the statement line? Which errors have been thrown? You need to provide a little more information so that we can help you.

Comment: I put ```"SELECT * FROM table WHERE  var1= $1 AND var2= $2 AND newVar IN ($3);"``` where you had  ```'SELECT * FROM shops WHERE name = $1' ``` and then after the if statement I put ```echo json_encode($results);```. In my success function in the javascript I have ```if ((response[0][var2]) != null)``` which gives me the error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'var2' of undefined or null reference. The array is also being populated by the user.

Comment: What is `console.log(response);` showing in the console in your JavaScript? you need to analyze what the value of `response` is first before directly accessing its fields.

Comment: When I had the PHP file like before, response would pull the row of information that I wanted from the database. When I changed it to what you said to do, response gives the value null.

Comment: @user22 I analyzed the issue and I think I found a proper solution (see edit). Can you please try it?

Comment: I tried it and I keep getting this error: HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. I don't get this error when I run what I had before.

Comment: Please add these three lines to the beginning of your PHP to show all errors: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` We can't help you if you do not tell us what errors are thrown by your code.

Comment: This is all it says: ```ERROR rreadyState":4,"responseText":"","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error): error Internal Server Error```

Comment: I changed the ellipsis operator to `array_merge`. Please try it.
For showing the actual error you can add an error callback to your AJAX call: `error: function(err) { console.error(err.responseText); }`

Comment: I tried it and on edge I get: ```SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'var1'of undefined or null reference``` and on firefox I get: ```TypeError: response[0] is undefined javascriptFile.js:432:26 success http:// javascriptFile.js:432 jQuery 4 i fireWith A c``` Also, I've already had the error callback in my code and this is all I get.

Comment: This is an error in your JavaScript but I can't see this part in your question. Please edit your question and add the code where this error is occuring. It seems like the syntax of the PHP file is correct now.

Comment: Right now this is what I get when console.log(response): ```[object Array]: []
length: "0"```

Comment: Please check the edits. Essentially what I'm trying to do is populate a box with the value I pull from the database.

Comment: If you want to have the format of the postgres query result like `response[0]['var2']` you need to transform it like this in your PHP code or JavaScript code (not recommended). Is there an option to share your whole code in order to try it out?

Comment: Unfortunately due to security reasons, I am unable to share the entire code. It does not necessarily have to be in the format of response[0]['var2']. I just need a way to access the information in the row. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Approach it step by step. First, I've added `echo json_encode($results);` to my solution because otherwise the AJAX call will just return an empty string. Second, just output `console.log(response);` in your JavaScript and send the result here. Based on this structure we can look for a way to use the returned data.

Comment: Yes I've had both lines of code in there and this is what I get: [object Array]: [] length: "0"

Comment: This could mean that there is no matching entry in the database. Can you add a database dump to your question please? This helps us to validate if the query is working in a correct way.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to do that but I have run the query on pgadmin and I know for a fact that this query definitely pulls a row of information

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE  var1= 'test' AND var2= 'testing' AND newVar IN ('grape', 'mango', 'apple');` returns a row?` Furthermore, add `$row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)` instead of `$ret`. It's hard to help you without knowing the actual code and data.

Comment: Yes it does return a row (There 100% is an entry matching the query).

Comment: It's working! Thank you for your help! I do have another question though. I want the program to run another query if the first one doesn't pull anything. I originally had it like this:```Select * from table where var1=   $myVar1PHP AND var2=   $myVar2PHP AND newVar IN ($myVarArrayPHP) UNION ALL Select * from table where var1=   $myVar1PHP AND var2=   $myVar2PHP AND NOT EXISTS (Select 1 From table where var1=   $myVar1PHP AND var2=   $myVar2PHP AND newVar IN ($myVarArrayPHP))``` Where can I implement this second query?

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea from a performance perspective to separate these queries. You could check using `count($results);` if the first query returned any results and if it's `0`, you can execute the second query using the same prepared statement "pattern" like for the first query.

Comment: First I need to understand your query. Why are you doing the same query again as a subquery for the `NOT EXISTS`? Or in other words: can you please explain what this query should return? Of course you can just replace the query in my answer with this query and adapt the `IN` part but I'm not sure if your query itself is efficient.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is first run this query: ```SELECT * FROM table WHERE  var1= $1 AND var2= $2 AND newVar IN ($placeholders);``` If this query returns 0 rows, I want the code to run this query: ```SELECT * FROM table WHERE  differentVar= $differentPostedVar AND var2= $2 AND newVar IN ($placeholders);``` If this returns 0 rows, I want to run a third query: ```SELECT * FROM table WHERE  3rdQ= $lastPostedVar ;```

Comment: @user22 Please have a look at my edit. Does it work for you? I would recommend to use a function to not write the same code over and over again.